How death is erased in the afterlife?
I want to ask a question out of curiosity, it's a matter of the afterlife.
In a hadith that I once read, that the Prophet said "death will be brought in the form of a black and white sheep, then the death will be slaughtered between heaven and hell."
Well, my question.
If death itself no longer exists, do all of Allah's creatures become immortal? Or only the inhabitants of heaven and hell?
Sorry if my question is a bit confusing.

The title of your question is asking "how", but the text asks "what will be immortal". Anyway, إِنَّ الدَّارَ الْآخِرَةَ لَهِيَ الْحَيَوَانُ, so that everything will be immortal, although it needs clarification when, e.g., you read كُلَّمَا نَضِجَتْ جُلُودُهُمْ بَدَّلْنَاهُمْ جُلُودًا غَيْرَهَا

The final and last stage of every human's life is the life of hereafter, either in the paradise or hellfire. People will live there forever. After a billion billion years, they will continue to live there.
Therefore, a human's life started at some point, and through different stages of life, will continue forever.
However, the key differences (as you alluded that you are confused) from Allah's life are:

Our lives are granted by Allah. Without Allah's decree, we would not and cannot exist.
There was a time when we did not exist. Allah created our souls and our bodies and then we came into being.
We do not have control over our life. We are not allowed to end our life in this world when we want.

On The Day of Judgement, death will die. All the people going to Jannah will be rejoiced by that, and all the people going to hellfire grieve and lament even more by that.
